# How to add content to Content Editor Webpart programatically?

Tags: development, web-part, 2010, publishing, web-part-pages

So I have the standard Content Editor Webpart (`MSContentEditor.dwp`). The title i can set via `webPart.Title` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.title.aspx)).

I can't find any property where I would set the content editor's content.

I basically want to provision the webpart to a publishing page (done), set it's title so something (done) and set some default content for it (stuck on this one). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ContentEditorWebPart wp = ....

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
var contentRoot = xDoc.CreateElement("ContentRoot");
contentRoot.InnerText = "Your text here";
wp.Content = contentRoot
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.contenteditorwebpart.content.aspx

Comment: That was easy :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :)

[ContentEditorWebPart.Content Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.contenteditorwebpart.content.aspx)

You might need to cast your WebPart to ContentEditorWebPart if you can't see this property.